# how to set http client cookie policy in apache camel

Tags: cookies, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use apache camel 2.19.1 and I **need to change COOKIE_POLICY**, that used by apache camel`s [http4 client](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html).
Please help me find best way to set it in route defined like this:

```
  <route>
    <from uri="direct:api_call"/>
    <to uri="http4://api_host"/>
  </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable cookies you can set the HTTP Client to ignore cookies by adding this URI option: httpClient.cookiePolicy=ignoreCookies

```
Ex. http4://api_host?httpClient.cookiePolicy=ignoreCookies
```